# Find all objects that have access to a particular role in snowflake

Tags: object, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, roles

I was wondering if there was a way to check what all objects does any particular role have access to, and with what privileges in snowflake. Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below command to get the privileges on the objects that a role has been granted access to. This will include the roles granted to the role too.

Show grants to role <role_name>;

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/show-grants.html#syntax

You can use the below command to get the details on the grants of the role to another role or user

Show grants of role <role_name>;

Answer (score 1):

To see what objects a role has access to, the following methods can be utilized.

1. SHOW COMMAND :

SHOW GRANTS TO ROLE;
Snowflake Documentation Reference: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/show-grants.html#show-grants

The **granted_on** column in the result if the above show command lists the name of the object, **privilege** column lists the name of the privilege and the **name** column lists the name of the role to which the privilege on the object has been granted.

2. Query the SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.GRANTS_TO_ROLES View.

   Documentation Reference: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/grants_to_roles.html#grants-to-roles-view